# What is the aircraft in the 'Be Altitude' album cover?

Tags: jet-engine, aircraft-identification

In 1972, the [Staple Singers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Staple_Singers) released the "[Be Altitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Be_Altitude:_Respect_Yourself)" album, which has them posing in a jet engine's intake.

[image]

My question is what aircraft does that engine belong to? And why would someone let them use it for a photo shoot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Its a Boeing 747 courtesy of Delta Airlines as per the album credits.](https://www.discogs.com/The-Staple-Singers-Be-Altitude-Respect-Yourself/release/851610) Photo by [Gerry Griffith](https://www.discogs.com/artist/1852888-Jerry-Griffith). For the [right amount of money its not that hard to take pictures in, on, or near jets](http://nymag.com/intelligencer/2017/10/you-can-rent-a-grounded-private-jet-to-take-instagram-photos.html).